Making the expression factoriseable $x^2 - y^2 - z^2 - x - 23y - 23z - 2yz$
Problem
Which positive integer should be subtracted from the expression such that the expression $x^2 - y^2 - z^2 - x - 23y - 23z - 2yz$ can be factorized?

My Attempt
The thing that was on my mind as soon as I saw the problem was to  balance the constants somehow by adding or subtracting a specific value so that the entire expression becomes a perfect square or can be expressed as the product of two factors. This will (I think) ensure that the expression is factorisable.
Keeping that in my mind, I began my approach.
We want to make the expression:
$x^2 - y^2 - z^2 - x - 23y - 23z - 2yz$
factorizable by adding a suitable negative integer.
I grouped the  terms to identify patterns:
$x^2 - x - \left(y^2 + z^2 + 2yz\right) - 23y - 23z$.
I recognized $y^2+2yz+z^2 = (y+z)^2$.
Substituting, I got :
$x^2 - x - (y + z)^2 - 23y - 23z$.
Let $u = y+z$ for simplicity:
$x^2 - x - u^2 - 23u$.
Now completing the square for $x^2-x$
For $x^2-x$, I  added and subtracted $\frac{1}{4}$ :
$x^2 - x = \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{4}$.
Substituting this back I get :
$\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{4} - u^2 - 23u$.
Next, I thought of completing the square for $u^2+23u$

"But I am uncertain about how to continue and I don't know if my approach will even work. Could someone please assist me with the next steps or give hints?"

Hint: The factorization is likely of the from $(x \pm y \pm z + a) ( x \pm y \pm z + b) $. (Why is this a good first guess?) 1/ What signs of $ \pm $ will give us $x^2 - y^2 - z^2  - 2yz$? 2/ What values of $  a, b$ will give us $-x - 23y - 23z$? 3/ Hence, what is $ab$?

See the writeup here for how to attempt to factorize quadratic forms like this by 1/ focusing on the quadratic terms, 2/ extracting the linear terms through a constant, 3/ verifying the product of constants. Arguably this could be considered an abstract duplicate.

@CalvinLin  once he reached  $f = x^2 - x - u^2 - 23 u^2,$  he could have multiplied by $4$ and arrived at a difference of squares in $4f - 528 = (2x-1)^2 - (2u + 23 )^2$  He even completed the square for $x$  and gave up

@WillJagy (FWIW OP even though of completing the square of $u^2 + 23u$, but didn't follow through which might allow them to recognize the difference of 2 squares.) $\quad$ Right, so I took that to indicate that he doesn't know how to factorize the "quadratic form", even if there were only 2 variables. That's partly why I linked out to an algorithmic approach that could work for many variables. $\quad$ Also, the naive completing the square doesn't alway work (See comment on user's solution.)

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Calvin Lin.

$\displaystyle \left( ~x - \frac{1}{2} ~\right)^2 = x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4}.$
Therefore, the goal should be to add or subtract some real number to the remainder of the expression so that the expression should be expressible as $~-1~$ times the square of some expression.
As your analysis shows, if you multiply the remainder of the terms by $~-1,~$ some of these terms become expressible as $~(y+z)^2.~$  So, the challenge is to somehow attempt to complete the square, on the remaining terms.
Suppose, for example, you consider what happens if $~r~$ is some real number, and you form the expression
$$(y + z + r)^2 = (y + z)^2 + r^2 + 2r(y + z).$$
By setting $~2r = 23 \implies r = \dfrac{23}{2},~$ you have formed the expression
$$\left( ~y + z + \frac{23}{2} ~\right)^2 = (y + z)^2 + \left( ~\frac{23}{2} ~\right)^2 + 23(y + z).$$
This works.
So, if you add the value
$$\frac{1}{4} - \left( ~\frac{23}{2} ~\right)^2 = -\frac{528}{4} = -132$$
to the expression, then the expression becomes
$$\left( ~x - \frac{1}{2} ~\right)^2 - \left( ~y + z + \frac{23}{2} ~\right)^2$$
which can be factored as the difference of two squares:
$$\left[ ~\left( ~x - \frac{1}{2} ~\right) - \left( ~y + z + \frac{23}{2} ~\right) ~\right] ~~~\times ~~~\left[ ~\left( ~x - \frac{1}{2} ~\right) + \left( ~y + z + \frac{23}{2} ~\right) ~\right]$$
$$= (x - y - z - 12) \times (x + y + z + 11).$$



$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Responding to the comment of Calvin Lin:

As an aside, trying to complete the square for $~x~$
and the rest of your calculations doesn't always work. In this was, we were lucky that the expression was of the form $~(x+A)(x+B).~$ 
Had the expression been of the form $~(x+A)(4x+B),~$
then completing the square to $~(2x+C)^2~$
would not have allowed us to continue from there.  
Whereas my alternative of "factorize the quadratic terms first" will always work (if a factorization exists).

Calvin Lin's comment seems intuitively reasonable, and I suspect that his analysis is accurate.  That is, I suspect that if the expression can be factored by merely adding some real number, then his method must work.
Actually, this is merely a suspicion on my part.  Prior to encountering this problem, I had never even heard of his approach.
Assuming that his approach always works, if the expression can be factored by adding a real number to the expression, his approach is somewhat problematic.  That is, this approach is more complicated than the basic completing the square approach that I was taught.  Here, I presumed that the OP (i.e. original poster) has also been taught about completing the square.
From the OP's work, the OP knew enough to try to identify patterns, but apparently had not been taught to automatically group the quadratic terms together.  So, I question whether the OP has been taught Calvin Lin's approach.
So, it is reasonable to speculate that the OP has been taught about completing the square, but has not been taught Calvin Lin's approach.  Assuming that this is true, then I suspect that the approach at the start of my answer represents the problem composer's intent.

The goal is to add some real number to
$$x^2 - y^2 - z^2 - x - 23y - 23z - 2yz \tag1 $$
to make it factorable.
I agree that the expression in (1) above, plus some real number, might well be factorable by expressing it as something other than the difference of two squares.
This was simply an obvious try on my part.

So, it seems worthwhile to use the approach in the MathSE question linked to by Calvin Lin.  I will attempt to do so now, even though I am not sure that I am doing this right:
The quadratic terms in (1) above are :
$$x^2 - (y^2 + z^2 + 2yz) = x^2 - (y+z)^2$$
$$= [ ~x - (y + z) ~] \times [ ~x + (y + z) ~]
= (x - y - z) \times (x + y + z). \tag2 $$
The remainder of the terms (i.e. the linear terms) in (1) above are
$$(-1) \times (x + 23y + 23z). \tag3 $$
At this point, speaking generically, I am out of my depth.
I have successfully factored the quadratic terms in (1) above, with the expression in (2) above.  However, it is unclear to me that the expression in (2) above is the only way to factor the quadratic terms.
I don't have the experience needed to have developed pertinent intuition here.
Anyway, it turns out that the expression in (2) above can be refined to include the expression in (3) above, plus some real number.
The obvious try, which works, is
$$(x - y - z + a) \times (x + y + z + b)$$
$$= x^2 - y^2 - z^2 - 2yz + ax + ay + az + bx - by - bz + ab.$$
So, you are solving for $~a,b~$ where

$~x(a + b) = -x \implies (a + b) = -1.$

$~(y+z)(a - b) = (y + z)(-23) \implies (a - b) = -23.$


This has unique solution $~(a,b) = (-12,11),~$ which implies that the real number to be added is $~(a \times b) = -132.$
This raises an issue which I am not qualified to have an opinion on:
Suppose that the original problem was altered so that the factors applied to the terms $~y~$ and $~z~$ (i.e. $~-23y -23z$) were unequal.  Given that the quadratic terms included $~-y^2 -z^2 - 2yz,~$ does this automatically imply that the altered problem can not be solved?

As an aside, trying to complete the square for $x$ and the rest of your calculations doesn't always work. In this was, we were lucky that the expression was of the form $(x + A) ( x + B)$. Had the expression been of the form $(x+A)(4x+B)$, then completing the square to $(2x+C)^2$ would not have allowed us to continue from there. $\quad$ Whereas my alternative of "factorize the quadratic terms first" will always work (if a factorization exists).

@CalvinLin +1 to your comment.  In response, see the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Proof that my algorithm work: Assume a factorization exists $=f \times g$. Let $f', g'$ be the parts without the constant, so $f = f' + a, g = g+b$ where $a, b$ are the constants.  Then $f'g'$ gives us the quadratic part (so that factorization exists and can further show its unique), $bf' + ag'$ gives us the linear part ( if $f', g'$ are not linear multiples, then any solution must be unique), and finally we have $ab$ as the constant term.$\quad$ Note, in the case where $f = k g$, for some real $k$, then we could have many solutions. EG For $x^2 + y^2 + 2xy + 4x + 4y$, we can add 3 or 4.

On continuing with your approach, here's a way.  You have reached $x^2-x-(u^2+23u)$ as the expression to be factored.  Notice that considering this a quadratic in $x$, we have sum of "roots" to be $1$ and the product of roots to be $-u^2-23u-c$ where $c$ is to be determined.  Now it is enough to split $23$ into two portions with difference $1$, and the product will be $c$. Obviously $c=11\cdot12=132$ does the job.
With this $c$, we have $u^2+23u+132=(u+11)(u+12)$, so the original expression factors as $x^2-x-(u+11)(u+12) = (x-u-12)(x+u+11)=(x-y-z-12)(x+y+z+11)$.
--
P.S.: This approach worked well in this case as the quadratic (in $x$) had the $y,z$ only in one coefficient).  You cannot always expect this and Calvin's comment is a more general approach.
